# Inheritance confused for association in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've got table/entity A. I've also got table/entity B.
B inherits from A. (B has a foreign key to A)

So far, no problem. EF is happy.

I have table/entity C which has a collection of B.
I add a foreign key in table B to C.

When I update my model, EF creates a relationship from C to A, not B. It is treating the table B as a type of associative table between C and A.

I hope I've described this situation well enough.

In any case, is there a way to accomplish what I want? I want C to have a collection of Bs not As.

**UPDATE**

In the EDMX editor, I manually deleted the association EF created, then I manually created my own desired association. I then had to map the association to the correct table. So far it seems to be working... but I wonder if there is a better way than my manual intervention.

Comment: You should bind to PrimaryKey of B to C.   Can you show what columns you are using for relationships?